# Select Items from List using Array

Tags: c#

Is there a better way to write this procedure?

```
    public List<IDenomination> GetInventory(int[] denominations)
    {
        var inventory = new List<IDenomination>();

        foreach (var denomination in denominations)
        {
            foreach (var item in Account)
            {
                if (item.Currency == denomination)
                {
                    inventory.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        return inventory;
    }
```

Comment: Account is a property contained within this class:  public List<IDenomination> Account { get; set; }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use some linq to do this fairly easily. Converting the array to a HashSet will allow Contains to operate faster

```
public List<IDenomination> GetInventory(int[] denominations)
{
    var denoms = new HashSet<int>(denominations);
    return Account.Where( a => denoms.Contains(a.Currency) ).ToList();
}
```

This assumes that Account : IDenomination though, as does your original code. If that were not the case, you would use a `.Select()` prior to `.ToList()` in order to select the IDenomination from Account.

Comment: When I try this I get: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'ToHashSet' and no extension method 'ToHashSet' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @TrevorBrooks - Ah yes, that was a custom extension. Please see my edit, it contains a native approach.

Comment: Also, if `Account` is changed much rarely than `GetInventory` method is called, it might be better to maintain `HashSet` over `IDenomination.Currency` values, and change the `GetInventory` method appropriately

Answer (score 2):

It's really not a great idea to return a `List` from your method if you can help it. You've effectively bound your code to always using a list. What if your client wants to use a `FancyCustomList<IDenomination>`? You'd have to do some messy casting.

By all means, use the Linq that @TravisJ provider, but you should change the signature to return a `IList<IDenomination>` instead.